# Installing ubuntu with windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm trying to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10. I have the extra space required for ubuntu (I have about 200GB set up for it) But when I try to install it I don't get the option to install it allongside windows. How can I install it while keeping windows at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu in another partition (if you are in doubt, just choose a partition to swap and another to /). Grub will be installed and windows 10 will be identified automatically resulting in dual boot option on boot.